# Как с помощью процедуры FilterRecord в Delphi сделать фильтр по дате?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
var
 t:Tdate;
 y,m,d:word;
 i:integer;
begin
 t:=Table1.Fields[0].value;
 DecodeDate(t,y,m,d);
 Accept:=(m = 3);
end;
```

Допустим у меня есть `CheckListBox` и в нем есть 12 месяцев,как сделать чтобы номера выбранных месяцев добавлялись в `Accept`

Answer (score 1):

Если предположить, что Accept - строковая переменная, то можно циклом записать в нее выделенные месяцы через пробел, а потом вывести например в Edit1. (Этот код логично было привязывать к событию клика по CheckListBox1).

```
var i:integer;
    Accept:string;
begin
  Accept:='';
  for i:=0 to CheckListBox1.Count-1 do
   if CheckListBox1.Checked[i] then
    Accept:=Accept+'(m='+IntToStr(i+1)+') ';
  Edit1.Text:=Accept;
end;
```

Вообще вопрос сформулирован как-то непонятно. В теме одно написано. В сообщении другое. Надеюсь я помог ответом своим...